# Is the loss value computed by keras for 2D CNN regression by keras point wise?

Tags: python, keras

I'm using keras for CNN on 2D images for regression with mean squared error as the loss function. The loss values are of the range 100. To know average error at each pixel, should I divide it by total number of pixels? Or the loss values displayed are for pixels?

Comment: Average error at each pixel? The loss values are displayed for an epoch.

Answer (score 0):

The way how `mse` is defined in Keras make it compute an average pixel error. So you could simply take a loss value as an average pixel error.