# Keras built-in MSE loss on 2D data returns 2D matrix, not scalar loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss-function

I'm trying to evaluate the MSE loss for single 2D test samples with an autoencoder (AE) in Keras once the model is trained and I'm surprised that when I call Keras MSE built-in function to get individual samples' loss it returns 2D tensors. That means the loss function computes one loss per pixel for each sample, and not one loss per sample as it should (?). To be perfectly clear, I expected MSE to associate to each 2D sample the mean of the squared errors computed over all pixels (as I've read on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47003117/8044858)).

Since I didn't manage to get an array of scalar MSE errors with one scalar per test sample after training my AE using `.predict()` and `.evaluate()` (perhaps I missed something there as well), I went on trying to directly use `keras.losses.mean_squared_error()`, sample by sample. This returned me 2D tensors as a loss for each sample (input tensors are of size `(N,M,1)`). When one looks at [Keras' original implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) of MSE loss, one finds:

```
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

The `axis=-1` explains why multiple dimensions aren't immediately reduced to a scalar when computing the loss.

I therefore wonder:

1. What exactly has my model been using during training ? Was it the
   mean of squared error over all pixels for each sample as I expected
   ? This isn't what the built-in code suggests.
2. Do I absolutely need to re-define the MSE loss to get the individual MSE losses for each test sample ? To obtain a scalar I
   would then have to flatten the samples and the associated
   predictions, and then re-apply the built-in MSE (and this sample by sample).

Manually flattening before computing MSE seems what needs to be done according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51855895/8044858) on Keras' MSE loss. Using MSE for an AE model with 2D data seemed fine to me as I read this [keras.io](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_denoising_autoencoder/) Mnist denoising tutorial.

My code:

```
import keras

AE_testOutputs = autoencoder.predict(samplesList)

samplesMSE = []
for testSampleIndex in range(samplesList.shape[0]):
    AE_output = AE_testOutputs[testSampleIndex,:,:,:]
    samplesMSE.append(keras.losses.mean_squared_error(samplesList[testSampleIndex,:,:,:],AE_output))
```

Which returns a list `samplesMSE` of `Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(15, 800), dtype=float64)` objects.

I'm sorry if I missed a similar question, I did actively research before posting, and I'm still afraid there is a very simple explanation/I must have missed a built-in function somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not absolutely required, Keras loss functions are conventionally defined "per-sample", where "sample" is basically each element in the output tensor of the model. The loss function is then pass through a wrapping function [`weighted_masked_objective`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L374-L424) that adds support for masking and sample weighting. By default, the total loss is the average of the samples losses.

If you want to get the mean of some value across every dimension but the first one, you can simply use `K.mean` over the value that you get.

Comment: what you say means that for my --> 1. Yes, a wrapping function I didn't know about actually computes the mean of pixel-wise SEs for each of my 2D samples (what "I expected") --> 2. Applying the **un-wrapped** version of the MSE Keras built-in loss  (what I did in this question's code sample) won't work because of the 2D nature of my samples, in order to obtain a similar loss for my test samples I need to manually re-define an MSE loss using a 2D-mean of pixel-wise SEs ? Just checking I got you right, and thanks for the answer !

Comment: @Blupon Yes that's right. What I meant is that if you do not want to redefine the loss function you could always do something like `keras.backend.mean(keras.losses.mean_squared_error(...))` which will compute the mean across the whole tensor. But you can also have your own MSE function since it's easy enough.